# real analysis question on equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can anyone verify my proof of the following problem found in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis chapter 7 exercise 15.

> Suppose $f$ is a real continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, $f_n(t)=f(nt)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{f_n\}$ is equicontinuous on $[0,1]$. What conclusion can you draw about $f$?

I think $f$ must be constant on $[0,\infty)$, that is I want to show that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$.
My proof goes as follows:
Let $\varepsilon>0$. By equicontinuity of $\{f_n\}$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for $\left|p\right|<\delta$ we have $\left|f_n(p)-f_n(0)\right|<\varepsilon$. Let $x\in (0,\infty)$, then for $n$ large enough we have $x<n\delta$ and $\frac{x}{n}<1$. Set $p=\frac{x}{n}$ then we have $\left|p\right|<\delta$ and so, \begin{align*}
\left|f(x)-f(0)\right|=\left|f(np)-f(0)\right|=\left|f_n(p)-f_n(0)\right|<\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$.

Nowhere in my proof did I use the continuity of $f$, so I wonder if I'm making a mistake.